# Find a shared_ptr in an unordered_set with only a const shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, constants, unordered-set

I have an `unordered_set<shared_ptr<T>> us` and I would like to know whether a needle `k` is in `us`, but `k` has type `shared_ptr<T const>` so `unordered_set<shared_ptr<T>>::find` complains that it cannot convert.

Is there a way around this? Maybe by directly supplying the hash?

I did try `const_cast` (and felt dirty) but that didn't cut it.

Comment: Not sure about this .... can `shared_ptr<T>` and `shared_ptr<T const>` own the same object, won't you have 2 owner blocks for the different object types?

Comment: @RichardCritten There's an implicit conversion from `shared_ptr<T>` to `shared_ptr<T const>` that does the right thing.  But also, you can even have `shared_ptr<T>` and `shared_ptr<int>` share ownership, using the aliasing constructors.  (That might be used to produce a shared pointer to a member of a class which is owned by a shared pointer. When the last pointer sharing ownership is destroyed, the original deleter is called, ignoring the type of the last shared pointer.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`std::const_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) is a possible solution here.

```
us.find(std::const_pointer_cast<T>(k));
```

Since you're not modifying `k`, it's okay to cast away the const.